# How does flask-sqlAlchemy deal with primary keys that are json?

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, jsonb

I am new to flask and sqlAlchemy. Any help will be great.

I have my models as:

```
class ReferentialDatum(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'referential_data'

    sid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    venues = db.Column(db.JSON, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    exchange_tickers = db.Column(db.JSON)
    trading_date = db.Column(db.Date, primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    total_volume = db.Column(db.BigInteger)
    last_trade_price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    last_reference_price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    exchange_close_price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    adjusted_close_price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    close_price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    close_price_source = db.Column(db.Text)
    insertion_time_utc = db.Column(db.DateTime(True), server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    last_updated_time = db.Column(db.BigInteger)
```

Note that I am using venues as a json field in my models and it is also a primary key.

In my function I have:

```
def ListProtobuf(Reference_data):

        venues = {"Canada1":1, "Canada2":1}
        exchange_tickers =  {"AAPL":1, "APL":1}
        trading_date = datetime.date.today()
        item = ReferentialDatum.query.filter_by(sid=Reference_data.security_id,trading_date=trading_date,venues=venues)

        if item.count()>0:
            item.update({"total_volume":sum(Reference_data.total_volume),"last_trade_price":Reference_data.last_trade_price,"last_reference_price":Reference_data.reference_price,"last_updated_time":Reference_data.update_time})
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            entry = ReferentialDatum(sid=Reference_data.security_id,exchange_tickers=exchange_tickers,venues=venues,trading_date=trading_date,total_volume=sum(Reference_data.total_volume),last_trade_price=Reference_data.last_trade_price,last_reference_price=Reference_data.reference_price,last_updated_time=Reference_data.update_time)
            db.session.add(entry)
            db.session.commit()
```

When I try to insert a new row(which does not exist earlier) I get the following error:

```
File "mini_conda/envs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchem /orm/identity.py", line 97, 
in __contains__ if key in self._dict:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

However if I remove primary_key=True from my models on the venues field.I do not get this error.

Any idea on why is this happening. Does ORM use fields that are primary keys as keys of some dict which gives this kind of error.How do I correct this error given that I require primary_key=True.